# UICollectionView self sizing not working for long text

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Below code working but when come to long text then it's cutting some of text show just according  view frame width for example `replacing it with abstractions or using data normalization to avoid redundancy.`

`replacing it with abstractions or using data n` showing other content not showing

```
class AyatWordByWordViewController : UIViewController {

        let celled = "celled"

        var texts : [String] = ["Don't", "repeat", "yourself", "is a principle", "of", "software development", "aimed", "at", "reducing", "repetition of software patterns", "replacing it with abstractions or using data normalization to avoid redundancy."]

        //word by work
        var collectionView : UICollectionView!

        override func viewDidLoad(){

           let alignedFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            alignedFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
            collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: alignedFlowLayout)
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.register(AyatTableViewWordByWordItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: celled)
            collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
           self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
                collectionView.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 150, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)


            if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
               // flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
                flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height:1)
            }
        }
    }

    extension AyatWordByWordViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return texts.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:celled, for: indexPath) as! AyatTableViewWordByWordItemCell
                cell.subTitleLabel.text = texts[indexPath.item]
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            return cell
        }

  }
```

**cell :**

```
public func fillSuperview() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if let superview = superview {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

**Used:**

```
subTitleLabel.fillSuperview()
```

[here is the output iPhoneX OS12.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQxSV.png)

Comment: did you set 0 lines to the label?

Comment: @iDevid i did it

Comment: Can you post your cell constraints?

Comment: @iDevid check updated code

Comment: Have you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on the label?

Comment: @HeroAlom still you have issue or solved?

Comment: @Rudedog  I did not set it.

Comment: @VishalParmar my problem not solved

Answer (score 0):

Please try below `code`

```
 let layout = yourCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
 layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize        
 layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 93, height: 31)
 layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 9, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Give label leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints with cell i hope its work for you